# Dynamic Grouping of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a set of variables in a python List(A,B,C). Using this list of variables I have to group the records in a dataframe. As the list may contain any set of variables each time, I want to do the grouping dynamically by passing the list as an argument to the groupby() instead of mentioning variable names. Please provide your suggestions.
Example:
df:
emp_id  dept    location
1       d1  East
2       d2  West
3       d2  west
4       d1  West
5       d2  East
6       d3  East
7       d2  West

list1 = ['dept','location']

df1 = df.groupby(['dept', 'location']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df['percent']= df['count']/df['count'].sum()

Obtained output:
o/p:
dept    location    count   percent
d1      East        1       0.14
d1      West        1       0.14
d2      East        1       0.14
d2      West        3       0.43
d3      East        1       0.14

Here the grouping is done with a constant set of variables(dept,location). However, i want to pass the variables dynamically to groupby function, since each time my dataframe may contain different set of variables. So i tried to store the column names in a list and pass it to groupby function, but its not working.

Comment: You gotta give sample data and what should your expected output look like and what have your tried so far. If not you are not going to get any solutions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example